# What is the exact value of $\eta(6i)$?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, modular-forms

Let $\eta(\tau)$ be the *Dedekind eta function*. In his *Lost Notebook*, Ramanujan played around with a [related function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function#Special_values) and came up with some of the nice evaluations,

$$\begin{aligned}
\eta(i) &= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}\\
\eta(2i) &= \frac{1}{2^{11/8}} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}\\
\eta(3i) &= \frac{1}{2\cdot 3^{3/8}} \frac{1}{(2+\sqrt{3})^{1/12}} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}\\
\eta(4i) &= \frac{1}{2^{29/16}} \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{2})^{1/4}} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}\\
\eta(5i) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{-1/2}\, \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}\\
\eta(6i) &=\; \color{red}{??}\\
\eta(7i) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}\left(-\tfrac{7}{2}+\sqrt{7}+\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{-7+4\sqrt{7}} \right)^{{1/4}}\, \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}\\
\eta(8i) &= \frac{1}{2^{73/32}} \frac{(-1+\sqrt[4]{2})^{1/2}}{(1+\sqrt{2})^{1/8}} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}\\
\eta(16i) &= \frac{1}{2^{177/64}} \frac{(-1+\sqrt[4]{2})^{1/4}}{(1+\sqrt{2})^{1/16}} \left(-2^{5/8}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1/2}\,\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}\end{aligned}$$

with the higher ones $>4$ added by this OP. (Note the powers of $2$.)

> **Questions**:
>
> 1. Similar to the others, what is the exact value of $\eta(6i)$?
> 2. Is it true that the function,
>      $$F(\sqrt{-N}) = \frac{\pi^{3/4}}{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}\,\eta(\sqrt{-N}) $$
>      *is an **algebraic number** only if $N$ is a square?*

**P.S.** It seems strange there is a function that yields an *algebraic number* for square input $N$ and a *transcendental number* for non-square $N$. (Are there well-known functions like that?) For an example of non-square $N$, we have,

$$\eta(\sqrt{-3}) =  \frac{3^{1/8}}{2^{4/3}} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{3}\big)^{3/2}}{\pi} = 0.63542\dots$$

and $F(\sqrt{-3})$ seems to be transcendental.

Comment: Have you seen van der Poorten and Williams, Values of the Dedekind eta function at quadratic irrationalities, Canad J Math 51 (1999) 176-224?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: No, but I just found a copy [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.324.4839&rep=rep1&type=pdf). It has 49 pages of math, but their main result (Theorem 9.3) for $\eta\left(\frac{b+\sqrt{d}}{2a} \right)$ involves a product of gamma functions of form $\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)$. It doesn't seem to address the special case when $d$ is a square and the **only** gamma factor needed (apparently) is $\Gamma \big( \tfrac{1}{4}\big)$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. Can this title be improved upon? See the comments of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852787/how-to-derive-relationship-between-dedekinds-eta-function-and-gamma-frac?noredirect=1#comment5886485_2852787

Comment: I'm sure you're likely aware, but there does exist a general formula for $\eta\left(\sqrt{-\lambda}\right)$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{N}$. See proposition 1 [here](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/299.pdf).

Comment: @KStarGamer Actually, haven't come across that paper before. But Myerson back in 2015 (see first comment above) did refer to a paper co-authored also by Williams (same author of your link). However, they tackled the general case $\eta\big(\sqrt{-\lambda}\big)$ and ended up with a semi-complicated formula (p.1641). If they had a secondary proposition for the special case when $\lambda$ is a square, I assume this formula has a simpler form.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After persevering with a *Mathematica* session, I found that $F(6i)$ is the root of $96$-deg eqn (no wonder it was hard to find!) but could be prettified as,

$$\eta(6i) = \frac{1}{2\cdot 6^{3/8}} \left(\frac{5-\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{3^{3/4}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1/6}\,\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$$

However, the second question is still open.

---

$\color{blue}{Update}$: Four years after this question was asked, Giuseppe Manco found a more elegant *factorable* formulation in this long [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101157/additional-values-of-dedekinds-eta-function-in-radical-form),

$$\eta(6i) = \frac{1}{2\cdot 6^{3/8}} \big(2-\sqrt3\big)^{1/24}\, \big(\sqrt2-\sqrt[4]3\big)^{1/4}\, \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$$

Comment: (+1) I think that our two answers together reply to the the first part of the question. I found a good evaluation technique but I wasn't brave enough to carry the computations till the end, but with this closed form AND my answer there is very little to add.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Thanks, but could you elaborate more on how your answer addresses Question 2?

Comment: I haven't touched yet the second part.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: I was using an old _Mathematica_ version plus some intuition to get this $96$-deg algebraic factor. I believe the new _RootApproximant_ has a default upper bound for the degree, and which may be adjusted.

Comment: Just for fun, $$\eta(6i) = \frac{\left(\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{3}-\sqrt{3}+1\right)\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)^{1/6}}{3^{3/8}\cdot2^{65/24}}\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$$

Answer (score 15):

Since we know the value of $\eta(3i)$, the point is just to compute the value of the product:
$$ \prod_{n\geq 0}(1+e^{-6\pi n})=\exp\sum_{n\geq 0}\log\left(1+e^{-6\pi n}\right)=\exp\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{6\pi n}{1+e^{6\pi s}}\,ds$$
where:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{6\pi n}{1+e^{6\pi s}}\,ds = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{6\pi s\,}{1+e^{6\pi s}}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{6\pi\{s\}}{1+e^{6\pi s}}$$
and the first integral in the RHS equals $\frac{\pi}{72}$ by the residue theorem, while expanding the fractional part as its Fourier series, $\{s\}=\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(2\pi n s)}{\pi n}$, we get:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{6\pi\{s\}\,ds}{1+e^{6\pi s}}&=&\frac{\log 2}{2}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{6 \sin(2\pi n s)}{n(e^{6\pi s}+1)}\,ds\\&=&\frac{\log 2}{2}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{6}{n}\sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(2\pi n s)\,e^{-6\pi m s}\,ds\\&=&\frac{\log 2}{2}-\frac{3}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{9 m^2+n^2}\\&=&\frac{\log 2}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{3}{\pi}\sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^m}{9m^2+n^2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and the last series just depends on the number of ways to represent a positive integer $\not\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ through the binary quadratic form $n^2+9m^2$: it is, with minor manipulations, just a Dirichlet convolution. I have just applied the same techniques of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316061/infinite-sum-involving-number-of-solutions-to-k-i2j2/1316180#1316180), just in reverse.

This shows a clear connection between the evaluation of the Dedekind eta function at quadratic irrationals and the class number problem: $\eta(\sqrt{-N})$ depends on $\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\frac{r(n)}{n}$, where $r(n)$ counts the number of ways to represent $n$ as $a^2+Nb^2$. If $N$ is a square or $a^2+Nb^2$ is the only reduced quadratic form of discriminant $-4N$ (class number one) we may explicitly compute such series, and it turns out that $F(\sqrt{-N})$ is an algebraic number. Otherwise, $\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\frac{r(n)}{n}$ is not even a convolution of Dirichlet series, hence your conjecture is very likely to hold.

Ultimately, the computation of $\eta(6i)$ can be carried on by recalling that:

$$j(\tau)=\left(\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}\right)^8+2^8\left(\frac{\eta(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^{16}\right)^{3} $$
and by computing the Klein $j$-invariant $j(3i)$. The Wikipedia page gives:

$$ j(3i) = \frac{1}{27}(2+\sqrt{3})^2(21+20\sqrt{3})^3.$$

Comment: The Wikipedia page for $j(\tau)$ is currently inconsistent; the value given is the one for $J(3\mathrm{i}) = j(3\mathrm{i})/1728$. Therefore the $1/27$ should actually be a factor $64$.

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{m, n\in\mathbb{Z}} '\frac{(-1)^{m}}{9m^{2}+n^{2}}=4\sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{9m^{2}+n^{2}}+\frac{17\pi^{2}}{54}$$ and the sum on the left in above equation can be evaluated using this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2482542/72031

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the second question is very simple.
Assume the complete elliptic integral of the first kind 
$$
K(x)=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2(\theta)}}=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot {}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;x^2\right).
$$
Then if we define the elliptic singular modulus $0<k_r<1$ to be the solution of 
$$
\frac{K\left(\sqrt{1-k_r^2}\right)}{K(k_r)}=\sqrt{r}\textrm{, }r>0,
$$
we know that $k_r$ is algebraic for $r$ positive rational. Assume the notation: 
$$
K[r]:=K(k_r)\textrm{, }r>0
$$
Also for $r_1,r,N$, such that $N$ positive integer, $r\in Q^{*}_{+}$, with $r_1=N^2r$, we have
$$
\frac{K[N^2r]}{K[r]}=M_N(r)
$$ 
The function $M_N(r)$ is called: "the multiplier" and for $r,N$ as above it is an algebraic number.

The Dedekind eta function is just
$$
\eta(z)=\eta_1(q):=q^{1/24}\prod^{\infty}_{n=1}\left(1-q^n\right)\textrm{, }q=e^{2\pi i z}\textrm{, }Im(z)>0.\tag 1
$$ 
We want to find $\eta(i\sqrt{r})$, $r>0$. For this we define the Ramanujan eta function
$$
f(-q):=\prod^{\infty}_{n=1}\left(1-q^n\right)\textrm{, }q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}}\textrm{, }r>0.\tag 2
$$
The function $f(-q)$ can evaluated at $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}}$, $r>0$ as (see [W,W] Chapter 21 pg.488):
$$
f(-q)=\frac{2^{1/3}}{\sqrt{\pi}}q^{-1/24}(k_r)^{1/12}(k'_r)^{1/3}K[r]^{1/2}\tag  3
$$
Assume that $q_1=e^{-\pi\sqrt{r_1}}$, with $r_1=N^2r$ and $GCD(N,r)=1$, ($r_1,N,r$ are integers, $N>1$ and $r$ is square free), then from (1),(2),(3) we have:
$$
\eta(i\sqrt{r_1})=\eta(i\sqrt{N^2r})=q_1^{1/12}f(-q_1^2)=algebraic\cdot \frac{\sqrt{K[4r_1]}}{\sqrt{\pi}}=alg\cdot\frac{\sqrt{K[4N^2r]}}{\sqrt{\pi}}=
$$
$$
=alg\cdot \sqrt{M_2(r)}\sqrt{M_{N}(r)}\frac{\sqrt{K[r]}}{\sqrt{\pi}}
$$ 
Hence if $r_1$ is a square (which means $r=1)$, then
$$
\eta(i\sqrt{r_1})=alg\cdot\sqrt{\frac{K[1]}{\pi}}=alg\cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\pi^{3/4}}
$$
Q.E.D.

Note:
$k'_r=\sqrt{1-k_r^2}$. $k'_r$ is called the coplementary modulus.

References

[W,W]: E.T. Whittaker and G.N. Watson. 'A course on Modern Analysis'. Cambridge U.P. 1927.

Comment: This was helpful for me while I was reading this answer: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1oalacxzlx

Answer (score 4):

While giving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2603326/72031) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2596065/72031) I got all the ingredients necessary to solve the current problem.

---

Consider the nome $q=e^{-\pi} $ so that elliptic modulus is $k=2^{-1/2}$ and the function $f(q) $ defined by $$f(q)=q^{1/6}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{4n})\tag{1}$$ which is expressed in terms of modulus $k$ and complete elliptic integral $K=K(k) $ as $$f(q) =2^{-2/3}\sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi}}k^{1/3}k'^{1/12}\tag{2}$$ (see first answer linked above).

If $l$ is the elliptic modulus corresponding to nome $q^{3}$ then we have $$\eta(6i)=f(q^{3})=2^{-2/3}\sqrt{\frac{2L}{\pi}}(l^2\sqrt{l'})^{1/6}\tag{3}$$ The values $$\sqrt{\frac{2L}{\pi}} =\frac{(27+18\sqrt{3})^{1/4}\Gamma(1/4)} {3\sqrt{2}\pi^{3/4}} ,l=\frac{(\sqrt{3}-1)(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[4]{3})}{2},\sqrt{l'}=\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[4]{3}(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2^{5/4}}$$ are available from the second answer linked above which help us to get the value of $\eta(6i)$ in explicit form. The calculations are somewhat lengthy but can be performed using pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about the findings of this post as well as this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852787/how-to-derive-relationship-between-dedekinds-eta-function-and-gamma-frac?noredirect=1#comment5886485_2852787). If we like the question I can ask it as a new question for the site but it may be that this type of thing is trivially shown not to be the case with some counterexample or maybe it follows quickly: I am not sure.

Let $\alpha = (-\frac{3}{4})!\pi^{-\frac{3}{4}}$ then we have seen that for the set $S=\{\frac{1}{n} : n\in \mathbb{N} \}\cup \mathbb{N}$ we have that

$\eta (Si)\subset A[\alpha]$. So a natural question might be: is it the case that $\eta(\mathbb{Q}i)\subset  A[\alpha]$?

I am already changing my completely unverified conjecture:

Maybe it's more like there is some transcendental number $t_m$ we can associate with each $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\eta(i\{x:x \in \{ \frac{m}{n}\} \cup \{ \frac{n}{m} \} \})\subset A[t_m]$? What we know is that this $\eta$ function needs to respect multiplicative inverses in someway.

Comment: The answer to your question is settled thanks to [Chowla & Selberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chowla%E2%80%93Selberg_formula). If $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}}, r\in\mathbb {Q}^{+} $ then the corresponding elliptic integral  $K$ can be expressed in terms of values of the Gamma function at rational points. Thus the value of the corresponding eta function is expressible in terms of values of Gamma function and $\pi$ (and some algebraic factor of course).