# The exact value of an infinite sum $e^{-n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Good morning! I'm having trouble with this problem...

how can we find the exact value of
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2}.$$
Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Simply there is no closed form of this sum.

Comment: look up jacobi theta functions

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says this here $$\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\vartheta
   _3\left(0,\frac{1}{e}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Are you sure the exponent is squared? If not, then the exact value is easy to find.

Comment: @Clayton, If the exponent non squared it's clear at all that is a progression geometric series such that convergent

Comment: @zera: I’m not sure what you said, but it sounds like you agree with me. If so, then you understand why I ask if the OP made a typo.

Comment: If you had $e^{-n^2\pi\sqrt{r}}, r\in\mathbb {Q}^{+} $ in place of $e^{-n^2}$ then you could get closed form of the sum. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2596065/72031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** This may helping you and assured that no closed form exist only it is a special case for $\theta$ and $\psi$ functions

The sum :$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2}$  is a particular case of  $\psi$ function at $\displaystyle x=\frac 1 \pi$ which is defined as :$\displaystyle\psi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x}.$ , For more information try to check  (Edwards 2001, p. 15)and satisfies  the functional equation :$\displaystyle\frac{1+2\psi(x)}{1+2\psi(x^{-1})}=\frac {1}{\sqrt{x}}$ , In your case you have :$\displaystyle \frac{1+2\psi(\pi)}{1+2\psi({\pi}^{-1})}=\sqrt{\pi}$ , and for more information about this you can see :(Jacobi 1828; Riemann 1859; Edwards 2001, p. 15)
.