# How to derive relationship between Dedekind's $\eta$ function and $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})$

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals, dedekind-eta-function

I am trying to determine in what way to approach finding a connection between [Dedekind's Eta Function](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/DedekindEta/), defined as $$\eta(\tau)=q^\frac{1}{24}\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)$$
where $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$ is referred to as the nome.

and the Gamma Function $$\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx$$ More specifically I would like to understand through what methods these identities are derived: $$\eta(i)=\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})\frac{\pi^{-3/4}}{2}$$
$$\eta(2i)=\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})2^{-11/8}\pi^{-3/4}$$
And in general what seems to be $$\eta(ki)=\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})\pi^{-3/4}C_{k}$$
for whole numbers $k$ and some constant $C_k$ Where $C_k$ [looks to be algebraic for $k\in 1,2,3,4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function#Special_values).
I guess what I really want to know is why does this factor of $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})\pi^{-3/4}$ come into play at imaginary integer values for the $\eta$ function?

I know there is a relationship between the $\eta$ and Jacobi Theta Functions that can be found using the Pentagonal Number Theorem or Jacobi's Triple Product Identity but I do not know how it fits into evaluation of $\eta(ki)$.

EDIT:My attempt at an answer: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^{2p}} dx=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2p})}{p}$$ can be derived through substitution. $$\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{2p})}{p^2}=\int_\Bbb {R^2}\exp(-(x^{2p}+y^{2p})dxdy$$
Applying the coordinate transformation $x^{2p}+y^{2p}=r^{2p}$ with $x=r\frac{\cos(\phi)}{|\sin(\phi)|^{2p}+|cos(\phi)|^{2p}}$ and $y=r\frac{\sin(\phi)}{|\sin(\phi)|^{2p}+|cos(\phi)|^{2p}}$ I get$$\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{2p})}{p^2}=\int_{0}^\infty re^{-r^{2p}}dr\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi}{(\sin^{2p}(\phi)+\cos^{2p}(\phi))^{\frac{1}{p}}}$$
The integral over $r$ evaluates to $\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{p})}{2p}$

So$$\frac{2\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{2p})}{p\Gamma({\frac{1}{p})}}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi}{(\sin^{2p}(\phi)+\cos^{2p}(\phi))^{\frac{1}{p}}}$$
The integral is symmetric over $[0,\pi]$ and $[\pi, 2\pi]$ so we get $$\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{2p})}{p\Gamma({\frac{1}{p})}}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\phi}{(\sin^{2p}(\phi)+\cos^{2p}(\phi))^{\frac{1}{p}}}$$ Plugging in $p=2$ yields $$\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{4})}{2\sqrt{\pi}}=\int_{0}^\pi \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{\sin^4(\phi)+\cos^4(\phi)}}$$Using $u=\cos(\phi)$ I arrive at $$\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{4})}{2\sqrt{\pi}}=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{(2u^4-2u^2+1)(1-u^2)}}$$

$$\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{4})}{4\sqrt{\pi}}=\int_{0}^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{-2u^6+5u^4-3u^2+1}}$$
This looks to be similar to an elliptic integral but I am finding trouble reducing it to a form that I can evaluate.

EDIT: If I can evaluate the integral in terms of the Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind, I can use its relation with Jacobi's Third Theta Function to evaluate it in terms of $\eta$. Such that$$\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{4})}{4\sqrt{\pi}}=cK(k')=\frac{\pi}{2}\theta_3^2(q)$$
So that we arrive at the familiar form on the LHS $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})\pi^{-3/4}}{2}=\frac{\theta_3(q)}{\sqrt{2c}}$$

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334684/what-is-the-exact-value-of-eta6i

Comment: @Mason I don't see how my question is a duplicate. The other OP asks for the value of $\eta(6i)$ whereas I want to know why the ratio $\Gamma(1/4)\pi^{-3/4}$ appears in those values. The other question did not make mention of this at all.

Comment: The question does make mention of this? It is question 2 of his 2 questions. But I agree that the title of that question could use work.

Comment: @Mason In question 2, he asks if $C_k$ is algebraic which is not my question. My question is why or how the other ratio appears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is the link between the Dedekind eta function and elliptic integrals.

---

Let $\tau$ be purely imaginary and in upper half of complex plane and let $$q=\exp(2\pi i\tau) \in(0,1)$$ be the corresponding nome. Consider the elliptic modulus $k\in(0,1)$ corresponding to nome $q$ given in terms of $q$ via Jacobi theta functions $$k=\frac{\vartheta_{2}^{2}(q)}{\vartheta _{3}^{2}(q)},\,\vartheta_{2}(q)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb {Z}} q^{(n+(1/2))^{2}},\,\vartheta _{3}(q)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb {Z}} q^{n^2}\tag{1}$$ Let $k'=\sqrt {1-k^2}$ and we further define elliptic integrals $$K=K(k) =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx} {\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 x}}, \, K'=K(k') \tag{2}$$ The circle of these definitions is finally completed by the formula $$\frac{K'} {K} =-2i\tau\tag{3}$$ Let $\tau'$ be another purely imaginary number in upper half of the complex plane such that $$\frac{\tau'} {\tau} =r\in\mathbb {Q} ^{+} \tag{4}$$ Let the corresponding nome be $q'=\exp(2\pi i\tau') $ and the elliptic moduli be $l, l'=\sqrt{1-l^2}$ and the elliptic integrals based on these moduli be denoted by $L, L'$. Then from the relation $\tau'=r\tau$ we get via $(3)$ the modular equation $$\frac{L'} {L} =r\frac{K'} {K}, r\in\mathbb {Q} ^{+} \tag{5}$$ Under these circumstances Jacobi proved using the transformation of elliptic integrals that *the relation between moduli $k, l$ is algebraic and the ratio $K/L$ is an algebraic function of $k, l $*.

The Dedekind's eta function is related to elliptic integrals via the relation $$\eta(\tau) =q^{1/24}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^n)=2^{-1/6}\sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi}}k^{1/12}k'^{1/3}\tag{6}$$ Now let $\tau=i/2$ so that $q=e^{-\pi} $ and then from $(3)$ we have $K=K'$ so that $k=k'=1/\sqrt{2}$ and it is well known that for this value of $k$ we have $$K(k) =\frac{\Gamma^{2}(1/4)} {4\sqrt{\pi}} \tag{7}$$ From $(6)$ it now follows that $\eta(\tau) =\eta(i/2)$ is an algebraic multiple of $\Gamma (1/4)\pi^{-3/4}$.

Let $\tau'=ri, r\in \mathbb {Q} ^{+} $ so that $\tau'/\tau=2r$ is a positive rational number. As noted above if $l, L$ correspond to $\tau'$ then the relation between $l$ and $k=1 /\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic so that $l$ is an algebraic number and the ratio $K/L$ is an algebraic function of $k, l $ and thus $K/L$ is also an algebraic number. Thus from equation $(6)$ it follows that $\eta(ri) $ is an algebraic multiple of $\Gamma (1/4)\pi^{-3/4}$.

More generally it can be proved that if $r$ is a positive rational number then the value of $\eta(i\sqrt{r}) $ can be expressed in terms of values of Gamma function at rational points and $\pi$ and certain algebraic numbers.

---

Also let me complete the link between $\Gamma (1/4)$ and elliptic integrals starting with your approach. We have $$\frac{\Gamma ^2(1/4)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x}}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}}$$ and the integral can further be written as $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-(1/2)\sin^2 2x}}$$ Putting $2x =t$ we can see that it reduces to $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-(1/2)\sin^2 t}}=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-(1/2)\sin^2 x}}=2K(1/\sqrt{2})$$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for that in depth explanation! I was also unsure that I was heading in the right direction, but thank you for showing me where my approach would have gotten me.

Comment: forgive me if I am missing something obvious, but which trig identity did you use in the first line of completing my approach?

Comment: Never mind, I see that you use power reduction formulas. I should have attempted to reduce the integral in trig form, would have been easier than trying to do that with the non-trig form of the integral.

Comment: @aleden: from my very limited experience with elliptic integrals I have found the trigonometric form more useful.

Comment: I can see why, due to the abundance of useful trig identities, it makes it a much easier integral to manipulate.

Answer (score 3):

The Dedekind eta function is related to the Euler $\phi$ function by
$$
\eta(\tau)=q^{1/24}\phi(q)
$$
so, for example,
$$
\eta(i)=e^{-\pi/12}\phi(e^{-2\pi}).
$$
In his "lost notebook", Ramanujan reported finding special values of the Euler function, such as 
$$
\phi(e^{-2\pi})=\frac{e^{\pi/12}\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})}{2\pi^{3/4}}
$$
and therefore
$$
\eta(i)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})}{2\pi^{3/4}}.
$$
The special values that Ramanujan found have been proved by George Andrews and Bruce Berndt. See [Ramanujan's lost notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_lost_notebook).

The Wikipedia article on the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) says that Ramanujan found values for $\phi(e^{-\pi})$, $\phi(e^{-2\pi})$, $\phi(e^{-4\pi})$, and $\phi(e^{-8\pi})$, which correspond to $\eta(i/2)$, $\eta(i)$, 
$\eta(2i)$, and $\eta(4i)$. However, as you mention, the Wikipedia article on the [eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) reports as value for $\eta(3i)$ so Ramanujan must have also found $\phi(e^{-6\pi})$. I doubt that $\eta(ki)$ is known, but you have a plausible conjecture.

Comment: Wikipedia gives a closed form for $\eta(3i)$ and I suspect that maybe $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})$ is connected to an elliptic integral, which perhaps implies a connection with the Dedekind Eta Function due to its relation with Jacobi Theta Functions, in which the elliptic integral can be expressed in.

Comment: If possible, could you provide a link to the portion of Ramanujan's Notebook that proves these equations?

Comment: A paper by Berndt  at https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/articles/aachen.pdf has two relevant comments. The first is that the result that the value for $\phi(e^{-\pi})$ "is classical" and provides references. The second is that he, together with two others, has proved that $\phi(e^{-n\pi})/\phi(e^{-\pi})$ is algebraic for every positive integer $n$, and provides a reference for that.

Comment: I'm new to StackExchange. Can I not put <a> in comments?

Comment: Sorry... the phi function in Berndt's aachen.pdf is a curly-phi function that is a kind of theta function; it  isn't the Euler phi function. It's not clear that what he proved about it is relevant to your conjecture, although it seems like it might be.

Answer (score 3):

This is a long comment:

From the identity: $\eta(\frac{-1}{\tau})=\sqrt{i\tau}\eta(\tau)$  we can derive just a few more values for $\eta$ that don't appear on the wikipedia page. Taking $\tau=ki$.

$$\eta(\frac{-1}{ki})=\sqrt{-1i^2k}\eta(ki)$$

$$\eta(\frac{i}{k})=\sqrt{k}\eta(ki)$$

So now we should be able to get just a few more: 
Taking $k=1,2$ we get no new info but $k=3,4$ should get us closed forms for $\eta(i/3)$ and $\eta(i/4)$. So in this way we can see that if $\eta(ki)$ is an algebraic number times $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})\pi^{-3/4}$ then so is $\eta(i/k)$. This conjecture would extend to the "Egyptian fractions."

Answer (score 3):

The value for $k = 6$ is,

$$\eta(6i) = \frac{1}{2\cdot 6^{3/8}} \left(\frac{5-\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{3^{3/4}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1/6}\,\color{brown}{\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}}$$

More generally, your observation that $\eta(k\,i)$ is a product of an algebraic number and that particular ratio (in brown) is correct. For $k>6$ and $\eta(\sqrt{-N})$, see this post: [*What is the exact value of $\eta(6i)$?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334684/what-is-the-exact-value-of-eta6i)

Comment: I see, is there any explanation for why that ratio appears in those Eta function values? I believe that it may be related to an elliptic integral but I do not know if thats correct.

Comment: This was answered by Niko Bagis the link that was given: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334684/what-is-the-exact-value-of-eta6i#2262492